# Matrix for Sampling WR

Tags: r

Sampling with replacement from original data set of size 200. Calculate frequency for each value and assign zero's to non-occured values. Iterate the process say 10 times and store the results in Matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give too much background so here was my interpretation:

```
## You didn't specify what we were sampling from, so I just took it as all numbers from 1 to 200
x <- 1:200

## Sampled from x in sizes of 50 (because you didn't specify how big), with replacement, 10 times    
samp <- list()

for (i in 1:10){
  samp[[i]] <- sample(x, size = 50, replace = TRUE)
}

results <- list()
results.mat <- 1:200
for (i in 1:10){
  results[[i]] <- table(factor(samp[[i]], levels = 1:200))  
  results.mat <- cbind(results.mat, results[[i]])
}

View(results.mat)
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice work. If you please put the results in 10 vectors or in a matrix of 200 by 10. As I am interested in it. Thanks once again.

Comment: I edited in the requested changes, let me know how it looks

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its great, I want the same. Thanks @Harrison